# How to set email field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I'm making a user model in Django but getting an error regarding email field and the unique=True also not working on the email field.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    User_email  = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True,unique=True)
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

The error I am getting when I am trying to run the command "python manage.py makemigrations":

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'first_name' to user without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>    1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>    2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
>   Select an option:

Comment: You probably already migrated that model. Why do you add a primary key yourself? When you constructed the model without an explicit primary key, Django made one for you. So I suggest that you drop the `user_id` column.

Comment: I've edited my code and removed that user-id but the error is still there

Comment: @SapanZaveri: setting a default has no impact on that specific problem. Django does not know what to do with the `User_id` field.

Comment: @mohitchandel: likely it is a slightly different problem now...

Comment: @willem there are two problems there. First one is I mentioned above and 2nd one is 'unique=True' is not working for email

Comment: @mohitchandel: can you please edit your question, and provide the error message of the new problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please have a look now.

Comment: @mohitchandlel: now it is complaining about the `first_name`, you will need to provide values for existing records in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you already have users in your database. When you add a new field to User, there ends up being a blank spot in the database for the existing users.

However, your code is such that a blank spot is not permitted. As your code is currently, there must be a value in that spot for all users.

Your options:

**1. Wipe your database**

If you aren't far long in the development process, just reset your database to have no users. Then all should work properly.

**2. Let it be blank/null for some users and fix it later**

Add one of the following to your `User_Id` declaration. `default='DEFAULT VALUE', blank=True or null=True`That will let you continue along, but then you will need to fix it later for the older users.

I will also point out that your error is not about the email (`User_email`)field, but rather the `User_id` field. Just delete that entirely. Django models already come with a built in system for managing primary keys. It is the `pk`.